# Pandas : Create a dataframe from groupby and applying sum and mean both on different columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe

```
      medal      number Age 
      Gold        5     25
      Silver      4     30
      Bronze      3     45
      Gold        1     23
      Silver      2     12
      Bronze      3     16
```

And, I am trying to groupby on medal and get sum of 'number' and mean of 'Age'. I can do it in two lines but how to do it single line with pandas groupby.

I can do 1 operation at a time with

```
df.groupby(['medal'])['Age'].mean()
```

or

```
df.groupby(['medal'])['number'].sum()
```

And then merge maybe, Which is a long process. So how to achieve it in pandas way

Below is the desired output

```
       medal   number   Age
      Bronze     6      30.5
      Gold       6      24.0
      Silver     6      21.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate by dictionary for columns names with aggregate functions and add `as_index=False` for column from `medal` in output `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('medal', as_index=False).agg({'Age': 'mean','number':'sum'})
print (df1)
    medal   Age  number
0  Bronze  30.5       6
1    Gold  24.0       6
2  Silver  21.0       6
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the agg-method on groupby with a dictionary, like so:

```
df.groupby(['medal']).agg({'number': 'sum', 'Age':'mean'})
```